# Jquery animation not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I'm in the process of finishing up a site and just working on making it ie7 compat, however theres one basic script that moves 3 tabs up/down and it's failing to work what so ever. the code is below.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.lower').click(function() {

    $('#range-dropdown').animate({
    top: '315',
  }, 2000, function() {});
  $('#range-dropdown2').animate({
    top: '0',
  }, 2000, function() {});
      $('#range-dropdown3').animate({
    top: '0',
  }, 2000, function() {});
      $('.rangelist-container').animate({
    top: '715',
  }, 2000, function() {});
      $('#dropdown-holder').animate({
    marginBottom: '120px',
  }, 2000, function() {});
   });


   $('.lower1').click(function() {
   $('#range-dropdown2').animate({
    top: '315',
  }, 2000, function() {});
      $('#range-dropdown').animate({
    top: '0',
  }, 2000, function() {});
      $('#range-dropdown3').animate({
    top: '0',
  }, 2000, function() {});
     $('.rangelist-container').animate({
    top: '715',
  }, 2000, function() {});
        $('#dropdown-holder').animate({
    marginBottom: '120px',
  }, 2000, function() {});


    });

  $('.lower2').click(function() {
  $('#range-dropdown3').animate({
    top: '315',
  }, 2000, function() {});
    $('#range-dropdown').animate({
    top: '0',
  }, 2000, function() {});
    $('#range-dropdown2').animate({
    top: '0',
  }, 2000, function() {});
    $('.rangelist-container').animate({
    top: '715',
  }, 2000, function() {});
        $('#dropdown-holder').animate({
    marginBottom: '120px',
  }, 2000, function() {});


  });
 });
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

*all css values are declared in the stylesheet.

Comment: You'd save yourself a **lot** of typing if you'd just give those pulldowns classes.

Comment: hmm, how do you mean? i only very lightly dabble in JS to avoid having to use flash for simple animations. @pointy

Comment: I was thinking of all the repeated lines of almost-the-same code. It's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stray trailing commas all over the place, for example:

```
$('#range-dropdown').animate({
    top: '315', // <----------------- Right here
}, 2000, function() {});
```

Remove those so that it looks like this:

```
$('#range-dropdown').animate({
    top: '315'
}, 2000, function() {});
```

IE7 gets upset by those trailing commas but most other browsers let it slide and DWIM (Do What I Mean) instead of complaining.

Comment: oh, jslint looks very handy indeed, had no idea about it. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly stating the units. You are saying `'315'`, but what units is that in? Feet? Meters? Centimeters? Use `'315px'`, as it explicitly states the units.

Also, you don't need to write `function() {}` over and over. Just omit it completely.

Comment: unfortunatly that doesn't fix the issue, thanks for the headsup on omitting function though.